# No eclipse in "open with" menu ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I have a problem that drives me really crazy.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and installed eclipse without its installer but compressed file. Now I am trying to connect eclipse to all my source code - .c, .cpp, .java, etc but I cannot see the 'eclipse' from Open With - Other Applications - Show Other Applications in nautilus.
I have tried to add '%f' or %F' but didn't work at all.

Is there any solution?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: a simple google search would have answered this questions. `open with nautilus` gave me 4,100,000 results

Answer (score -6, accepted):

OP found the solution and posted this as the answer (in his question, so it was moved into a dedicated answer):

> I walked through the post over and found out I had another `eclipse.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications`. Once I deleted it, then the system successfully load the settings from `/usr/share/applications`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is that your File Manager (Nautilus?) has no "Open, With" context menu.

If so, this link might help:

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/458281/ubuntu-14-04-nautilus-has-no-menu-file-edit-etc-dont-exist
>
> - Run dconf-editor, navigate to org > gtk > settings > file-chooser, then untick show-hidden.

See also:

- [Ubuntu Fix: Add Program to List of Applications in “Open With” When Right-Clicking Files in Nautilus](https://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/ubuntu-fix-add-program-to-list-of-applications-in-open-with-when-right-clicking-files-in-nautilus/)

If this doesn't work, please specify:

- Which Ubuntu desktop you're using (Gnome 3?)
- Which file manager GUI you're using (Nautilis? Nemo?  Other?)
- Whether or not you see an "Open With" context menu at all; and, if so, what options are available

PS: Installing the .zip file should be OK.

Comment: pretty sure ubuntu uses nautilus, unless its changed recently, or my mind just isnt what it used to be...